# Getting a nested map within json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have JSON data such as this:

```
var data = '{"credit":{"@code":"NT2C8FFC","card":"NT2C8FFC","credit":"149.96","amount":"149.96","disabled":"0","expired":"2011-02-15 10:21:18","user":"xxxx","issued":"2010-02-15 10:21:18","orderid":[],"fromorder":[],"email":"xxxx","phone":[],"state":[],"address":[],"city":[],"zip":[],"country":[],"customerid":"xxx","order":"xxx","order_date":"2010-01-23 00:00:00","reason":"Product Not Working as Expected","source":"xxx","first":[],"last":[],"notes":[]}}'
```

It is actually being returned to me as JSON. I am just displaying it here like this for example sake. I can use `data["credit"]` to get the element called `credit` but that only gets me :

```
{"@code":"NT2C8FFC","card":"NT2C8FFC","credit":"149.96","amount":"149.96","disabled":"0","expired":"2011-02-15 10:21:18","user":"xxxx","issued":"2010-02-15 10:21:18","orderid":[],"fromorder":[],"email":"xxxx","phone":[],"state":[],"address":[],"city":[],"zip":[],"country":[],"customerid":"xxx","order":"xxx","order_date":"2010-01-23 00:00:00","reason":"Product Not Working as Expected","source":"xxx","first":[],"last":[],"notes":[]}
```

How can I drill down to one shot? `data["credit"]["credit"]` is not proper syntax. It results in undefined. I know I'm close but can't remember the rest. The goal is to get `149.96` from the JSON data.

Comment: [Why do you say it's not proper syntax?](http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/3Y6XH/)

Comment: @ExplosionPills 's fiddle works fine for me..

Comment: @ExplosionPills, your Fiddle does not include the quotes around the data which is why it works

Comment: possible duplicate of [I have a nested data structure / JSON, how can I access a specific value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/i-have-a-nested-data-structure-json-how-can-i-access-a-specific-value)

Comment: Could it be that you somehow double encoded your data and `data.credit` is a actually a string containing JSON? If so, fix your data!

Comment: This does work. I had been beating my head on it a while and it was my own mistake in the data sent so, data returned was not what I expected. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

For now you can use `alert(data.credit.credit)`.

```
        var data = '{"credit":{"@code":"NT2C8FFC","card":"NT2C8FFC","credit":"149.96","amount":"149.96","disabled":"0","expired":"2011-02-15 10:21:18","user":"xxxx","issued":"2010-02-15 10:21:18","orderid":[],"fromorder":[],"email":"xxxx","phone":[],"state":[],"address":[],"city":[],"zip":[],"country":[],"customerid":"xxx","order":"xxx","order_date":"2010-01-23 00:00:00","reason":"Product Not Working as Expected","source":"xxx","first":[],"last":[],"notes":[]}}';
        eval("data=" + data);
        alert(data.credit.credit);
```

You can also use `data = JSON.parse(data);` to convert the string into Json but this has browser compatibility issues.

These are the browsers that supports

- Firefox (Mozilla) 3.5
- Internet Explorer 8
- Chrome
- Opera 10
- List item
- Safari 4

Older versions dont support.

Comment: `.` or `[]` syntax will both work correctly for an object. Using `[]` syntax allows a variable to be used between the brackets, i.e. `var c='credit';console.log(data[c]);`

Comment: The example of "data" in the context is data being returned as a JSON object. That was why I used data["credit"]. I just can't get the inner credit.

Comment: "data" is a JSON object. My bad for putting quotes around it. data.credit.credit returns undefined.

Comment: *"You can also use `data = JSON.parse(data);` to convert the string into Json"*: No no no! You use `JSON.parse` to convert JSON into a native object / array. If you wanted to create JSON, you would take an existing object/array and pass it to `JSON.stringify`. [There is no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: @FelixKling: And what about the browser compatibility issues? Say I want this on IE7..will JSON.parse work?

Comment: But... didn't I share what I know (I even included a link)? I wasn't talking about the methods specifically, I was pointing out that your statement is incorrect (and this has nothing to do with showing someone down, this is preventing spreading an (unfortunately) common misconception). JSON is a textual data exchange format, like XML. You said you can use `JSON.parse` to convert the string into JSON, but it's the opposite: You use it to convert a JSON string into JS objects / arrays. It does not matter which method you use specifically.

Comment: I was referring to the json object initialized in the post and not to any string. Sorry, I misunderstood you, people here are criticizing other's answers so that their's goes up the line. Sorry again I really didnt mean to hurt you and yes you are doing a good job. Thanks for correcting me. And I also take back my comment.

Answer (score 0):

use `.` operator to get the object's object

```
alert(data.credit.credit) //gives 149.96
 alert(data.credit.amount) //gives 149.96
alert(data.credit.card) //gives NT2C8FFC
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making `data` a string not an object. Change

```
var data = '{"credit":{"@code":"NT2C8FFC","card":"NT2C8FFC","credit":"149.96","amount":"149.96","disabled":"0","expired":"2011-02-15 10:21:18","user":"xxxx","issued":"2010-02-15 10:21:18","orderid":[],"fromorder":[],"email":"xxxx","phone":[],"state":[],"address":[],"city":[],"zip":[],"country":[],"customerid":"xxx","order":"xxx","order_date":"2010-01-23 00:00:00","reason":"Product Not Working as Expected","source":"xxx","first":[],"last":[],"notes":[]}}'
```

to

```
var data = {"credit":{"@code":"NT2C8FFC","card":"NT2C8FFC","credit":"149.96","amount":"149.96","disabled":"0","expired":"2011-02-15 10:21:18","user":"xxxx","issued":"2010-02-15 10:21:18","orderid":[],"fromorder":[],"email":"xxxx","phone":[],"state":[],"address":[],"city":[],"zip":[],"country":[],"customerid":"xxx","order":"xxx","order_date":"2010-01-23 00:00:00","reason":"Product Not Working as Expected","source":"xxx","first":[],"last":[],"notes":[]}}
```

If you can't change the original data you will need to parse it by doing

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
```

(which will work in most browsers) or use a method from a library such as [JQuery's](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/):

```
data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```